# Parse nested saveInBackgroundWithBlock in iOS

Tags: ios, parsing, parse-platform

I am working on an iOS project that uses Parse for server backend. As part of my code I have the following saveInBackgroundWithBlock nested blocks.

```
// Save PFFile
[imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    ...
    [userPhoto saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {        
        if (!error) {
            self.profileDictionary[@"picture"] = userPhoto;

            NSLog(@"%@", self.profileDictionary);

            NSMutableDictionary *userProfile = self.profileDictionary;

            [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:userProfile forKey:@"profile"];
            [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saving User Profile Succeded\n\n\n\n");
                    // If user's info is saved, then let's just segue to the actual app
                    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"profileToMain" sender:self];
                } else {
                    // Log details of the failure
                    NSLog(@"Error while saving profile: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}];
```

As you can see, the code is mainly 3 `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` blocks nested together.

Everything works up until the third block, where it just hangs. I know this because the segue is not executed.

The main idea of the code is to save things one after the other. In other words, imageFile is a `PFFile` that gets saved first, then a the userPhoto `PFObject` is saved afterwards, and finally the userProfile, which has been pre-filled gets saved along with the new `PFObject` as part of it. This profile.

Any comments on why this hangs? How can I achieve this succession of saving objects to Parse without causing a hang?

I appreciate your help and time beforehand.

Comment: Have you tried `saveInBackgroundWithTarget:selector:` and putting the logic in a function? That way, once the save completes it calls your function and you can log/put a break point and see what's happening

Comment: I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure you can drop your entire `userPhoto saveInBackground` If you set a pointer to Object A in Object B and save Object B, Parse will automatically save Object A.  I'm not sure if this pertains to a dictionary the way you have it here, but you could do a quick test to see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than nesting sometimes what works for me is the PFObject SaveAll functionality where you can pass in an array of objects that save in the order they appear in the array, then they will all save and you can still execute a nested block of code once they all succeed.

```
[PFObject saveAllInBackground:@[Object1, Object2] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
     if(succeeded){
           //Your code to execute once finished
     }

}
```